# Spring Batch StepScope Bean

Tags: java, scope, spring-batch, partitioning

how the lifecycle of step scoped bean is exactly defined, especially in case when I have partitioned scope?

For example:

- gridSize = 4
- SimplePartitioner used as a Partitioner (will create 4 partition definitions)
- RepositoryItemReader as step scoped bean

The question is: how many parallel steps will be created assuming a simple flow (read, process, write, finish)? 4 parallel steps? Do every step has its own RepositoryItemReader, so in result there will be 4 RepositoryItemReaders?

Answer (score 1):

A bean that is step scoped will get one instance per StepExecution.  So using your example you will end up with four `RepositoryItemReader` instances, one per partition.  This allows the state of each partition to be independent to support things like restartability.